# query all dates within the date range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Spreadsheet that I'm querying and the date is set as `dd/mm/yyyy`.

How can I query between the start and finish (ref cells) of each month, so the query only returns dates between the ref cells.

This is what I was trying to re-code:

```
=QUERY('Calculated Pay [view]'!B1:B1000,”select * where B>=date”””&text(A2,”dd/mm/yyyy”)&””” and B<=date”””&text(B2,”dd/mm/yyyy”)&””””)
```

Answer (score 2):

QUERY expects dates to be in yyyy/MM/dd format:

`=QUERY('Calculated Pay [view]'!B1:B1000,"select * where B >= date '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")`

Comment: sorry says parameter 2 is wrong :/

Comment: Are you able to enter into a spare cell a formula that just returns the query string, and post the output here? ie ="select * ..."

Comment: sorry, tried that but didnt know how to get a result. this is the answer from hovering over #VALUE.

Unable to parse query string for Function. QUERY parameter 2: Invalid date literal [2014/08/01]. Date literal should be of form yyyy-MM-dd.

does that mean the dates being formatted backwards?

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm really sorry, as per the error message you quoted, the date format requires hyphens, not slashes. Answer edited. Truly a derp moment.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to add a column C with a formula such as:

```
=if(and(B1>eomonth(Sheet2!$A$2,-1),B1<=eomonth(Sheet2!$A$2,0)),"s",)
```

and apply a simplified query such as:

```
=query('Calculated Pay [view]'!B1:C1000,"Select B where C ='s' ")
```

Comment: should that be B1 then B2? in the if. i cant work out what your asking it

Comment: with your solution i get results but for july, not august. i thought changing the -1 to 1 or 0 might work....didnt :/

Answer (score -1):

```
=round(query(po, 
             "select count(AE)/count(Z)
              where Z>date'"&I6&"' 
              and Z<=date'"&J6&"' AND W='"&B7&"' 
              label count(AE)/count(Z)''")*100-100, 2) & "%"
```

Comment: Some explanation on what's going on here would make this a better answer.